# Facebook user locale on "user_denied" facebook app page

Tags: facebook

I want to display the correct user language on my Facebook app when the user denies the permissions. How can I do this? I want to achieve this without using the automatic translation process of facebook, I need to have my own translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are we talking about here, app on a website or canvas/page tab?

For the latter, the `signed_request` contains `user.locale`, even if the user has not authorized the app yet.

For a website app, there is no data available if the user hasn’t connected to the app yet (AFAIK). In that case you could only see what their client sends in the Accept-Language HTTP request header.

Comment: Perfect, it's a canvas tab so signed_request solved my issue. Many thanks.